# Slot Machine in C (gotoxy)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

int intSlot1, intSlot2, intSlot3;

void fnGotoXY(short x, short y);
void fnSlotMachine();
void fnSlot1();
void fnSlot2();
void fnSlot3();

int main(){

        srand( time(0) );
        fnSlotMachine();
        fnSlot1();
        fnSlot2();
        fnSlot3();

}

void fnGotoXY(short x, short y){

        COORD pos = {x, y};
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);

}

void fnSlotMachine(){

        fnGotoXY(5, 5);
        printf(" x^---------------------------^x\n");
        printf("      |oOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOoOo|\n");
        printf("      \\_____________________________/\n");
        printf("      /__$$$__\\  /__$$$__\\  /__$$$__\\");
        fnGotoXY(5, 12);
        printf(" <*^*^*^*>  <*^*^*^*>  <*^*^*^*>");


}

void fnSlot1(){

        while(1){
                Sleep(50);
                fnGotoXY(5, 9);
                intSlot1 = rand() % 9;
                printf(" | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
                fnGotoXY(2, 10);
                printf("    | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
                fnGotoXY(2, 11);
                printf("    | %i %i %i |",   intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
        }      
}

void fnSlot2(){

        while(1){
                Sleep(50);
                fnGotoXY(17, 9);
                intSlot2 = rand() % 9;
                printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
                fnGotoXY(17, 10);
                printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
                fnGotoXY(17, 11);
                printf("| %i %i %i |",   intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
        }
}

void fnSlot3(){

        while(1){
                Sleep(50);
                fnGotoXY(27, 9);
                intSlot3 = rand() % 9;
                printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
                fnGotoXY(27, 10);
                printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
                fnGotoXY(27, 11);
                printf("| %i %i %i |",   intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
        }
}
```

So, my problem is about the `gotoxy`. The other slots are not printing after I put the `while(1)` loop. Hoping for some response. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `while(1)` is an infinite loop. You don't seem to break it

Comment: But why is the other 2 slots not printing?

Comment: Because your first infinite loop in `fnSlot1()` never ends

Comment: Why are you surprised that an endless-loop does not end!?

Comment: I just thought that my implementation would work.. Just a newbie. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite loops in all functions. If you enter one function you never return.

Consider putting this while in main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
...

int main(){

        srand( time(0) );
        fnSlotMachine();
        while(1) {
          fnSlot1();
          fnSlot2();
          fnSlot3(); 
        }
}

...    
void fnSlot1(){

            Sleep(50);
            fnGotoXY(5, 9);
            intSlot1 = rand() % 9;
            printf(" | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
            fnGotoXY(2, 10);
            printf("    | %i %i %i |\n", intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);
            fnGotoXY(2, 11);
            printf("    | %i %i %i |",   intSlot1, intSlot1, intSlot1);

}

void fnSlot2(){


            Sleep(50);
            fnGotoXY(17, 9);
            intSlot2 = rand() % 9;
            printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
            fnGotoXY(17, 10);
            printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);
            fnGotoXY(17, 11);
            printf("| %i %i %i |",   intSlot2, intSlot2, intSlot2);

}

void fnSlot3(){


            Sleep(50);
            fnGotoXY(27, 9);
            intSlot3 = rand() % 9;
            printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
            fnGotoXY(27, 10);
            printf("| %i %i %i |\n", intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);
            fnGotoXY(27, 11);
            printf("| %i %i %i |",   intSlot3, intSlot3, intSlot3);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `while(1)` loops from the `fnSlotN` functions and instead:

```
while(1)
{
    fnSlot1();
    fnSlot2();
    fnSlot3();
}
```

Comment: That is what I just did. Thanks for the response, Kind Sir!